# Thickness of proton exchange membrane (Nafion)?

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, ions, electrons, protons

I am looking into using a proton exchange membrane for a bio-energy cell experiment. Previous scholars have been using Nafion as a PEM to place between the anode and cathode (air-cathode). the thickness of the material is about  (7-mil). I was wondering, would the ion transfer rate get better if I used a thinner version of the same material due to a decrease of distance! or would it cause electrons to go through!

I would really appreciate it if someone can point me.

Thanks

Comment: Thinner membranes may contain unwanted tiny holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, the ion transfer rate gets better with a decrease in distance. However, it is harder to implement thinner PEM depending on the application. The method of fabrication might cause smaller PEM to be less selective despite them shorting the distance between the electrodes.